# Uploading Image from android file system to Firebase Storage

Tags: android, angular, firebase, ionic4, firebase-storage

I am currently creating a page that allows users to take pictures of both their identity card and selfie of themselves, however, i am not able to get the files from the file system to upload it using submitpicture().

Here is my typescript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { EmailComposer } from '@ionic-native/email-composer/ngx';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-verifyidentity',
  templateUrl: './verifyidentity.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./verifyidentity.page.scss'],
})
export class VerifyidentityPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public camera: Camera, public file: File, private modalController: ModalController, public emailComposer: EmailComposer) { }

  nric: any;
  selfie: any;
  nricimageData: any;
  selfieimageData: any;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  takenric() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
      cameraDirection: 1
    }

    this.camera.getPicture().then((imageData) => {
      this.nricimageData = imageData
      let filename = imageData.substring(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      let path = imageData.substring(0, imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      this.file.readAsDataURL(path,filename).then((base64data) => {
        this.nric = base64data;
        firebase.storage().ref().child("test").put(imageData).then(snapshot => {
          console.log('Uploaded image ');
        });
      })
    });     
  }

  takeselfie() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
      cameraDirection: 1
    }

    this.camera.getPicture().then((imageData) => {
      this.selfieimageData = imageData
      let filename = imageData.substring(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      let path = imageData.substring(0, imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      this.file.readAsDataURL(path,filename).then((base64data) => {
        this.selfie = base64data;
        firebase.storage().ref().child("test").put(imageData).then(snapshot => {
          console.log('Uploaded image ');
        });
      })
    });     
  }

  submitpicture() {
    firebase.storage().ref().child("nric").put(this.nric); // this does not work!

}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to get the image from the android system with the file path and store it in a variable before uploading to firebase storage with submitpicture().

So sorry for any inconvenience caused and thank you.

Best regards,
Dan

Comment: Do you call `takenric` before you do `submitpicture`?

Comment: Yes, it would be called before submitpicture() is called.

Comment: And what is the issue? Do you get any error? What do you see when you print `this.nricimageData`?

Comment: Here is it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u_bg-omgrC23ttWzSDlkUZahbcNb3eGj/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I was wondering if it would be possible to just upload the pictures with the file directories, but i do not think that is possible. Or would there be any other ways to upload the images? I do not have any errors so far.